# Chef not calling the attributes defined in a template

Tags: ruby, tomcat, chef-infra, jmx

can anyone suggest on what is going wrong here.

I am using 2 templates for JMX: jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password. The user in the `jmxremote.access` and the username & password are set as attributes available in the data_bag,

The files looks like this (just showing where the variables are declared):

jmxremote.access:

```
# o The "monitorRole" role has readonly access.
# o The "controlRole" role has readwrite access and can create the standard
#   Timer and Monitor MBeans defined by the JMX API.

      <%= @jmx_user %>   readonly

#controlRole   readwrite \
#create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \
#unregister
```

jmxremote.password:

```
#
# Following are two commented-out entries.  The "measureRole" role has
# password "QED".  The "controlRole" role has password "R&D".
#
# monitorRole  QED
# controlRole   R&D

  <%= @jmx_user %>   <%= @jmx_pass %>
```

In the recipe, they are called as below:

```
template '/opt/mount1/java/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access' do
  source 'jmxremote.access.erb'
  mode 00600
  owner 'tomcat'
  group 'tomcat'
  variables(
    :jmx_user => credentials['zabbix_user']['username']
  )
  notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]", :delayed
end

template '/opt/mount1/java/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password' do
  source 'jmxremote.password.erb'
  mode 00600
  owner 'tomcat'
  group 'tomcat'
  variables(
    :jmx_user => credentials['zabbix_user']['username'],
    :jmx_pass => credentials['zabbix_user']['password']
  )
  notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]", :delayed
end
```

the values are available in the data_bags, i have confirmed that. The strange thing is, Chef run completes. But it leaves the variables unwritten in the files.

Note: if i manually put in the values in the 2 files, tomcat starts okay until the next chef-client run. The scheduled chef-client run - wipes the manual entries as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is this something to do with the formatting of the lines in the 2 files: jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password.? If i place the variables right at the beginning of the left of the file, it seem to include the values of the variables.

Comment: i think, i spoke too fast. Everything seem to work with the existing files when i perform a kitchen test with the same version of the cookbook

Comment: so, the /etc/chef/client.rb was missing the path to "encrypted_data_bag_secret". I edited the file and did a "chef-client" on the node. Its still doesn't fill the files on the server with the variables whose values are in the secret

Comment: How is defined you `credentials` variable ? Sounds like the culprit is here (giving nil values). You may ensure they are properly defined by adding a `log "Jmx user  is: #{credentials['zabbix_user']['username']}"` resource or `Chef::Log.info "Jmx user  is: #{credentials['zabbix_user']['username']}"` in your recipe

Comment: @Tensibai, - the issue got fixed very strangely. While looking into it there was a ruby syntax error for a different local variable, pointed out by a fren of mine. I corrected that pushed up the code to chef-server. The chef-client run on the node, fixed the main issue. I am not sure how it started working. I am still trying to figure out what went wrong initially.  BTW: the data_bags are loaded using the below provider    "credentials = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("#{node.chef_environment}", "#{node.chef_environment}")" in the recipe

Comment: Usually the chef logs are of some value to found problems, specially when run with `-l debug` to get more information on what's going on. Here with your description I assumed the chef run was successfull and it should not be the case with a syntax error unless the resource have `ignote_failure true` attribute. So I really can't tell why you experienced that.

Comment: yes, the debug log for the chef-client didn't gave any clue on miss to dump in the variable values from the encrypted data_bags. If i had put in the values by hand on these files the chef-client run will remove them back. So, it behaved like there was noticed declared for those variables. Anyways - i am still searching in the dark for a clue. But this looks to be one of issue for me not for chef at large.